# If $X$ is from (canonical) exponential family, do we always know the distribution of $T(X)$?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution, exponential-family

Assume $X$ are generated by a distribution from exponential family,

$$ f(X; \theta) = h(X)\exp\{\eta(\theta)T(X) - b(\theta)\}$$

After solving several exercises with various distribution functions, I've noticed that it is often the case that the distribution for $T(X)$, $X=(X_1, \ldots, X_n)'$, has roughly the shape of:

$$ 2\eta(\theta)T(X) \sim \chi^2(2n)$$

Is there a known fact when and if this is case? Is there a more general result?

My guess is that $T(X)/\eta(\theta)$ would reduce the distribution to canonical exponential, and due to relationshiop between Exponential and Chi-squared distributions this somehow comes up as a result.

Comment: counter point to Chi-squared hypothesis: discrete random variables

Comment: Good point. So it's clear that additional conditions apply (at least cointinuity). Also, $\chi^2$ here is merely an observation, it would be interesting to find some general result.

Comment: @CliffAB also, I haven't checked _all_ discretes, but i.e., $T(X)$  for Poisson [seem to relate to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Related_distributions) non-centered $\chi^2$,